# Time has disappeared from menu bar (Mac OS X SL)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, date-time

Since the last update to Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6.3) the time has disappeared from my menu bar when I go into the Date & Time pane in System Preferences and click on the 'Show date and time in menu bar' it doesn't let me.  Is this a noted bug? and can it be fixed easily?

Comment: It means you are out of time. It was nice knowing you. :)

Comment: My last update was 10.6.2 - have you come back from the future? :-)

Comment: seriously - does the system log reveal anything wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After several days trying to fix this I decided to reinstall the OS.

Comment: That seems drastic for something that should be easy to track down.

Comment: post re-worded.

Answer (score 3):

Try Logging out, use a different user, and move the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist out of your ailing user directory.  Then Log back in.  I suspect everything will be fine then.